# Qt get a threads ID in the main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have some issues with this:

First I create my object and move it to a thread:

```
FileUploader *fileUploader = new FileUploader(fileList_, start, (offset == 0 ? (fileList_.count() - start) : offset));
QThread *fileUploaderThread = new QThread;
fileUploader->moveToThread(fileUploaderThread);

fileUploaderThreads_.append(fileUploaderThread);
fileUploaders_.append(fileUploader); // contains pointers to the objects

connect(fileUploader, SIGNAL(progressChangedAt(int)), model_, SLOT(reportProgressChanged(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(fileUploader, SIGNAL(statusChangedAt(int)), model_, SLOT(reportStatusChanged(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(fileUploader, SIGNAL(finished()), fileUploaderThread, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(fileUploaderThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(checkIfFinished()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

The in the slot checkIfFinished() I wanna go though all the threads and see if they quit. 
    qDebug() << "one thread done";

```
foreach(QThread *thread, fileUploaderThreads_) { // or FileUploader* fileuploader, fileUploaders_ ?
    if(thread && !thread->isFinished()) {

        qDebug() << "not finished " << thread->currentThreadId();

        return; // not done
    }
}
```

When this is printed out, I only get the main thread Id, not the threads. I tried to print the threads id's out but with no luck (after they are started ofc). 
The reason why I'm doing this I because the person writing "Advanced Qt Programming - Mark S" did a similar thing with QThreads that he placed in a list and checked if they where finished. The only thing thats working now is the connection which kills the thread when the fileUploader is done.

Also, how do I store pointers for the threads? I wounder how I will be able to delete them all if they don't seem to point to the right threads.

Edit:

I tried to store the QObjects in a list instead and do this:

```
QThread *senderx = qobject_cast<QThread*>(sender());

qDebug() << "one thread done" << senderx;

foreach(FileUploader *fileUploader, fileUploaders_) {
    if(fileUploader && !fileUploader->thread()->isFinished()) {

        qDebug() << "not finished " << fileUploader->thread();

        return; // not done
    }
}
//done 
qDebug() << "done";
setButtonState(false);
```

And my outprint on the last call is :

> one thread done QThread(0x43ee180)
>
> not finished  QThread(0x43ee180)

How is this possible? It is done, but the method says otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want `QObject::thread()`, not `QThread::currentThreadId()` - the second one returns the thread that the function was called in.

Once you fix that, your pointers will work fine.

Comment: That worked. But my program doesn't seem to get that they are all done every time I run it for some reason.

Comment: In your edit, what function is that (in what object) and where is it being called from?  We can take this to chat if you'd like.

Comment: the function is "checkIfFinished". yeah sure

Comment: I don't know if I can invite you directly, but I started a room called Qt Threading Discussion

Comment: oh, still need the answer to how to get the id of the workerthread? QObject::thread()::currentThreadId() only gives me the main thread id even if I call if after the thread is started

Comment: That function will return the id of the thread where the call was executed - meaning, you need to call it from *within* that thread, rather than *on* that thread (it is a `static` method of `QThread`, so it isn't acting *on* an object at all).  In your case, you could have a slot in `FileUploader` and access it with a queued connection - that way the call will be be executed in the event loop of the thread acting on the `FileUploader` object.